# Use AWS lambda to upload video into S3 with download URL

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I want to upload video into S3 using AWS lambda function. This video is not available in my local computer. I have 'download URL'. I don't want to download it into my local computer and upload it into S3. I am looking for a solution to directly put this video file into S3 using lambda function. If I use buffer or streaming, I will consume lots of memory. Is there a better efficient solution for this?

I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Could you please clarify where you are copying the file FROM?

Comment: Hi John, In my project I need to upload videos which are available behind an API. These videos are available in cloud, and I have download URL. I need to send it directly to S3 using Amazon lambda without download it locally.

Comment: When you say "videos are available in cloud", exactly WHERE are they available? From S3, Google, Dropbox? Or just from some random URL?

Comment: Hi John, They are available in cloud of  video conference tool. We have API to access video details. I have to put those video into S3.

Comment: @Dasu Is your question how to download files using lambda and how lo upload them to s3 using lambda?

Comment: Hi Usman, My question is download files into S3 directly using 'download URL'. I don't want to download them locally and upload them into S3. I want to check AWS lambda can handle download URL and get the files into S3 directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could certainly write an AWS Lambda function that would:

- Download the file from the URL and store it in `/tmp`
- Upload to Amazon S3 using the AWS S3 SDK

It would be easiest to download the complete file rather than attempting to stream it in 'bits'. However, please note that there is a **limit of 500MB of disk space** available for storing data. If your download is larger than 500MB, you'll need to do some creative programming to download portions of it and then upload it as a multi-part upload.

As for how to download it, use whatever library you prefer for download a web file.

Answer (score 26):

I had the same question and developed the following quick solution that is not dependent on the `/tmp` disk limits. It uses download stream as a file-like object.

Features:

- No external python modules, using AWS Lambda Python 3.6 builtin boto3 and urllib3
- Has chunked reading built in, good for downloading large file
- Efficient connection and memory usage through urllib3 pool management
- Using configurable upload_fileobj builtin multipart and threaded upload

  ```
  import boto3
  import botocore.vendored.requests.packages.urllib3 as urllib3

  def lambda_handler(event, context):

      url='http://yourdownloadurl/file.tgz' # put your url here
      bucket = 'aws-s3-bucket' #your s3 bucket
      key = 'folder/filename' #your desired s3 path or filename

      s3=boto3.client('s3')
      http=urllib3.PoolManager()
      s3.upload_fileobj(http.request('GET', url,preload_content=False), bucket, key)
  ```

Comment: Best answer ! Just tried with quite heavy files, it works

Comment: How about adding a version where it zips it before uploading?

Comment: Doesn't work using botocore 1.15.39.  AttributeError: module 'botocore.vendored.requests.packages.urllib3' has no attribute 'PoolManager'.  verified urllib3 1.25.8 does have it

Comment: my lambda is located in a different account than my S3. above code does drop the file into S3 but i can't access it from S3. any help?